# Internet works on VPN but doesnt in ethernet connection

Tags: wifi, vpn, ethernet, internet-connection

I wanted to ask you what you think about my problem.
My internet connection works just fine while I connect with VPN but it doesnt work, or works extremely slow, while on ethernet. It worked just fine until today a couple hours ago. First, I thought it was a problem with my provider so I called them twice and they said that everything looks okay from us, and then I just spontaneously opened VPN (psiphon3) and tried connecting to the internet and it magically works!
I hope everything is understandable of what my problem is!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows, you should check if proxy is disabled.
So go in Internet Options (in search bar or run inetcpl.cpl) → Connections tab → LAN Settings button and disable Proxy server.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/cant-open-any-webpage-after-using-psiphon/435d04c4-ca99-4dbd-9897-fa2c1df6775f

Comment: Thank you, dude! I really appreciate your help ♥.